# Syntax error eval'ing an assignment

Tags: python, syntax-error, eval

For some reason, when I run

```
import sys
from fractions import Fraction
for i, j in zip(["a","b","c","d","e","f"], range(1,6)):
    eval("{0} = int(sys.argv[{1}])".format(i, j))
if a*d != c*b:
    x = (e*d-b*f)/(a*d-c*b) 
    y = (a*f-c*e)/(a*d-c*b)
    print "x = ", x , ", y = ", y
elif e*d-b*f == 0 and a*f-e*c == 0:
    print "Infinite solutions"
    print "Slope = ", Fraction(-a,b), ", Y-Intercept = ", Fraction(e,b)
else:
    print "No solution"
```

using `python2 py.py 1 3 3 9 5 15`, it gives me the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py.py", line 4, in <module>
    eval("{0} = int(sys.argv[{1}])".format(i, j))
  File "<string>", line 1
    a = int(sys.argv[1])
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas as to why this happens? I'm certain it's valid syntax but maybe the eval messed with it?

Comment: why on Earth would you use `eval` for this... why not a dictionary? or an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a needless use of `eval`.  Your code:

```
for i, j in zip(["a","b","c","d","e","f"], range(1,6)):
    eval("{0} = int(sys.argv[{1}])".format(i, j))
```

can be better expressed as:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f = map(int, sys.argv[1:7])
```

or as:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f = (int(x) for x in sys.argv[1:7])
```

[Note that the original code had the range wrong, it should be range(1,7)]

Comment: I didn't know you could do that in python! I guess I wasn't asking the actual question I needed the answer to which was "how do I assign the arguments to these variables (without it looking awful)". Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First of all (as others pointed out), evaluating code here is totally uncalled for (not to mention the performance hit). See  e.g. [Ned's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26919983/648265) for one alternative.

Now, regarding the error itself:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=eval#eval:

> The expression argument is parsed and evaluated as a Python expression (technically speaking, a condition list) using the globals and locals dictionaries as global and local namespace.

The key phrase is *"as a Python expression"*. Assignment is not an expression but a statement. There is [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec) to execute statements.